# Selenium Fluent WebDriver - Click does not work as expected

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing

I have a pagination list, that is essentially constructed like so (I am using AngularJS):

```
<span id="latestResultsIndicator">    
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="Item.action()"><span>1</span></li>
        <li ng-click="Item.action()"><span>2</span></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

This works great in HTML, but when I try to write an integration test using Selenium WebDriver and the [Fluent API](http://fluent.stirno.com/docs/#getting-started) I run into problems.

Specifically I want to click on the second `li`, to do this I am using the following code

```
I.Assert.Exists("#latestResultsIndicator");
var secondPageElement = I.Find("#latestResultsIndicator ul li:nth-child(2)");
I.Click(secondPageElement);
```

This doesn't actually work! If I use jQuery in the Chrome console to do `$("#latestResultsIndicator ul li:nth-child(2)").trigger("click")` then the second page is selected, so I know the selector is correct.

To test further I added a double click like so:

```
I.DoubleClick(secondPageElement);
```

What I noticed here is that the very first `li` gets selected.  Its as if its trying to click or select the wrong one! (See the image).

[image]

What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I know Webdriver has some issues with css pseudo-selectors such as nth-child.  You might be able to make it work with Xpath, which is just as fast and just as flexible.

```
var webDriver = (IWebDriver)I.Provider;
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='latestResultsIndicator']//ul//li[2]")).Click();
```

Not sure if it will work or not, as I have not used FluentAutomation.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea and does progress me, but it just throws another error. I think Selenium won't let me click a `li` element.  Although if I use the Firefox IDE plugin it allows it!! Here is the exception: `unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (829, 177). Other element would receive the click: <div paging="" page="pageOptions.Page" page-size="pageOptions.ResultsPerPage" total="pageOptions.TotalResults" paging-action="navigateToPage(page)" show-prev-next="false" adjacent="1" class="paginationContainer ng-isolate-scope">...</div>`

Comment: Looks like your <li> element is covered by something.  You could force it with javascript I suppose, but I wouldn't know how to do that with FluentAutomation.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector as it is written in your question is not correct

```
"#latestResultsIndicator ul li:nth-child(2)"
```

The UL has the id you're looking for, so it should be

```
"ul#latestResultsIndicator li:nth-child(2)"
```

Not sure whether that is going to solve your problem, but it's a place to start. If not, please update with the results

Comment: Thanks Steve, actually that was a problem with my question. I must have edited it wrong whilst putting it up. Updated accordingly